# How is ViewsRecent in search results calculated?

Tags: 2013, search, rest

I need to find the top 3 visited webs for the last 4 weeks and I need/want to do it via the REST search api. This is SharePoint 2013.

The value *ViewsRecent* returned by a search query seems to be what I'm looking for. According to [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2014/01/22/add-and-configure-the-recommended-items-and-popular-items-web-part-in-sharepoint-server-2013.aspx) blog article the default timespan for the value of *ViewsRecent* is 2 weeks. The article also mentions a possibility to change the timespan that is used to calculate the value of *ViewsRecent* but the author does not (yet) say how. Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score -1):

The author of the aforementioned article just published the second article that shows how to modify the value that is used to calculate ViewsRecent: http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2014/01/28/view-and-configure-usage-analytics-reports-in-sharepoint-server-2013.aspx

Comment: Valid values of RecentPopularityTimeFrame is in the range 1 - 14.

Comment: Link is now dead.

Answer (score -1):

```
/_api/search/query?querytext='Path:https://sharepoint.com/sites/test/Lists/COMPActivity'&sourceid='d46e3'&selectproperties='ListItemID,Title,Path,ViewsRecent'&processbestbets='true'&enablequeryrules='true'&rowlimit='200'&trimduplicates='false'&sortlist='ViewsRecent:descending'&startrow=0
```